# How can we use v-for and v-if in the same element?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am building a component in which I have to iterate over each action and check conditions on each action. So, how can I use `v-for` and `v-if` in the same element?

Answer (score 5):

The Vue.js [Style Guide](https://vuejs.org/style-guide/rules-essential.html#avoid-v-if-with-v-for) recommends against this:

> **Never use `v-if` on the same element as `v-for`.**
>
> There are two common cases where this can be tempting:
>
> - To filter items in a list (e.g. `v-for="user in users" v-if="user.isActive")`. In these cases, replace users with a new computed property that returns your filtered list (e.g. `activeUsers`).
> - To avoid rendering a list if it should be hidden (e.g. `v-for="user in users" v-if="shouldShowUsers")`. In these cases, move the `v-if` to a container element (e.g. `ul`, `ol`).

Your best option is to use a `<template>` tag for your `v-for` and apply your `v-if` inside that on whichever HTML tag you're using. For an instance:

```html
<template v-for="(user, index) in users">
  <div v-if="user.isActive" :key="index">
     // your HTML code here
  </div>
</template>
```

or use a `computed` value as mentioned in the docs. For example, something like this:

```js
computed: {
  activeUsers() {
    return this.users.filter(user => user.isActive)
  }
}
```

Without seeing an example of your current code, I could only guess how you might adapt the above to suit your individual needs.